# Перенос с Google.Drive на Яндекс.Диск

Tags: google-drive, облако, облачное-хранилище

Встала задача о переносе всей информации (~650 гб) c Гугл Диска на Яндекс Диск. При простом скачивании на компьютер - гугл выдает ошибку после ~5 гб, есть ли какие-то решения?
Имеется также сервер на Linux.

Comment: Поставить 2 приложения и натравить их на одну папку?

Comment: А по подробнее можете подсказать, пожалуйста?)
Не совсем понял)

Comment: Поставить на пк приложение Я.Диск и Google Диск, и задать им рабочей дирректорией одну и ту же папку, тогда всё что скачает приложение гугл диска будет заливатся в облако яндекса, с пол года назад у гугла небыло ограничения в 5гб, приложение гугл диска у меня спокойно выкачало 20 гб данных на ПК